# Global winforms styling

Tags: winforms, styling

Are there global styles in Winforms as there are in WPF?
I'd like to be able to, for example, set `ForeColor` to be used by all the labels that exist within the app. Is there any solution, or do I have to do the changes manually for all the controls separately?

Answer (score 1):

Most controls will inherit the font from their parent - so try setting the font styles you want on the window.

Comment: Op is asking about Font color, I guess he means `ForeColor` etc.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Still tends to carry through

Comment: Ah, I wonder how I forgot. Yes ForeColor comes in [AmbientProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) list. +1

Comment: Sorry for the delay, what about other properties tho? Let's say, borders for instance. Also yeah, I meant ForeColor.